# Library support for Scala's NotNull trait

Tags: scala, notnull

**Notice:** As of Scala 2.11, `NotNull` is deprecated.

As far as I understand, if you want a reference type to be non-nullable you have to mixin the magic `NotNull` trait, and the compiler will automatically prevent you from putting `null`-able values in it. See this [mailing-list thread](http://www.nabble.com/Not-null-td19637829.html) for instance.

What lacking is, a decent library support for non-nullable types. If I would like to write a package that don't need to interface java code directly, and I want to prevent all types in this package from using `null` by default, I have no choice but to redefine all builting variables like so

```
//can't actually do that, but just to give the general idea
class NString extends String with NotNull
class NMap[X,Y] extends Map[X,Y] with NotNull
...
```

I expect scala to have (as a compiler plugin, or library) option for me to write

```
import collections.notnull._
```

in order to easily disallow `null` usage in a specific scala file.

Is there an option to easily force many usefull types in the standard library to be not-nullable?

Comment: You can extend String?  I thought it was marked final.

Comment: Actually you can't. Good point. Need to define NString with implicit conversion to string I guess.

Comment: I guess you look for something like `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` – and I miss that as well.

Comment: checkout the solution proposed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18604521/618089)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't really know what the deal is with `NotNull`, but I get the impression that Scala hasn't fully worked out how it wants to deal with NotNull/Nullable concepts. My own policy is to never use null in Scala, and if you call a Java API that may return null, *immediately* convert it to an `Option`.

This utility method is my best friend:

```
def ?[A <: AnyRef](nullable: A): Option[A] = if (nullable eq null) None else Some(nullable)
```

Then you do stuff like this:

```
val foo: Option[Foo] = ?(getFooFromJavaAPIThatMightReturnNull())
```

I find this far simplier than trying to track what may or may not be null.

So I didn't answer your question at all, but I pass this on in case it's useful...

**Update**: more recent Scala versions now support this in the standard API:

```
val foo: Option[Foo] = Option(getFooFromJavaAPIThatMightReturnNull())
```

Comment: The problem with your approach is, that the type system doesn't force me not to use null. So I can forget a Java API call, and have a null sneaking into my code without noticing. If OTOH all types are NotNullable, the compiler would shout if you did val x:String with NotNullable = javaapithatmightreturnNull().

Comment: `Option.apply` does the same things as your `?` function.

Comment: Indeed, but this was written before Option.apply existed.

Comment: Using Option is the generally accepted method to deal with functions that might return nothing, but it still means that you have to deal with cases where `foo` returns `None` and change the code that calls `foo` to `match` or `map` on the `Option`. If you know that foo will really *never* return `null`, then this complicates your code for nothing. The use of a simple tag `Foo with NotNull` gives you the semantic that the compiler needs for running extra checks without asking you to change anything in the calling code. See a solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18604521/618089).