# Mark method call that it always returns not null result

Tags: scala, nullable, compiler-warnings, notnull

Scala compiler has `-Xcheck-null` which tries to check if there are any potential null pointer dereference in runtime.

It's ok for me, but I get too much false positives, i.e. suppose I define logger :

```
private final val LOGGER: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[GenericRestImpl])
```

The method `getLogger` never returns `null`. How can I pass this knowledge to compiler so it will not complain?

```
[WARNING] TestImpl.scala:31: warning: potential null pointer dereference: LOGGER.debug
[WARNING]       LOGGER.debug("Using {} for sort", sortParam)
```

When I create new instance I can mark it with `NotNull` trait:

```
return new Foo() with NotNull.
```

That's ok, but what to do with objects returned from other methods? Especially if it is comming from 3rd party library? I don't like idea to mark all my variables as Optional, because it will add too much overhead. Also, I don't like idea to create implicit conversions (because it will require extra class for each class that I want to mark as NotNull.

I also checked question [Library support for Scala's NotNull trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522367/library-support-for-scalas-notnull-trait) but it didn't help to solve my problem.

Comment: You do understand right, NotNull trait is just a marker. It does nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jatin mentions, `NotNull` is just a marker or tag, so you can use `NotNull` to tag anything. The trick to do this is to forcing a cast your base type `with NotNull`.

So you can write something like this `"notnull".asInstanceOf[String with NotNull]`. It's a safe cast if you are sure it's never ever null.

In your actual example, you can therefore write:

```
private final val LOGGER: Logger with NotNull = 
   LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[GenericRestImpl]).asInstanceOf[Logger with NotNull]
```

While there is no need to create new types for this, it's a bit cumbersome if you have to do it a lot, so you could use some little utils to simplify/clarify the notation:

```
type NeverNull[T] = T with NotNull
def neverNull[A](a: A): NeverNull[A] = a.asInstanceOf[A with NotNull]
```

`NeverNull` is just an alias for any type `T` tagged with `NotNull` and `neverNull` is a little wrapper to tag any existing value of type `A` as being never null.

You can then use it as:

```
private final val LOGGER: NeverNull[Logger] = neverNull {
       LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[GenericRestImpl])
}
```

You could even make this an implicit conversion, if you are really sure of what you are doing:

```
implicit def neverNull[A](a: A): NeverNull[A] = a.asInstanceOf[A with NotNull]

private final val LOGGER: NeverNull[Logger] = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[GenericRestImpl])
```

Note that `NeverNull[Logger]` is still a `Logger`, so you can call any method of that class on it, or pass it on to functions that take as parameter a `Logger`.

This kind of construct is called an *unboxed tagged type* and is pretty useful, see other applications and discussion [here](http://etorreborre.blogspot.de/2011/11/practical-uses-for-unboxed-tagged-types.html) and [here](https://coderwall.com/p/l-plmq).